# Mapping LDAP groups to roles in JBoss 5

Tags: ldap, seam, jboss5.x

I'm trying to authenticate users of the administrative consoles (Admin, JMX, JBoss Web and JBoss WS) using an LDAP provider defined in `conf/login-config.xml`:

```
  <application-policy name="LDAP">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option>
        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldaps://ldap.company.com:636</module-option>
        <module-option name="java.naming.security.protocol">ssl</module-option>
        <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</module-option>
        <module-option name="bindDN">uid=dummy,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=company,dc=com</module-option>
        <module-option name="bindCredential">secret</module-option>
        <module-option name="baseCtxDN">cn=accounts,dc=company,dc=com</module-option>
        <module-option name="baseFilter">(&#038;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0}))</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=company,dc=com</module-option>
        <module-option name="roleAttributeID">dn</module-option>
        <module-option name="roleFilter">(&#038;(objectClass=posixgroup)(member={1}))</module-option>
        <module-option name="roleRecursion">-1</module-option>
        <module-option name="searchScope">SUBTREE_SCOPE</module-option>
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="searchTimeLimit">-1</module-option>
      </login-module>
      <!-- This login-module is used only in one use case, see below for details
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule" flag="optional">
        <module-option name="rolesProperties">props/admin-console-roles.properties</module-option>
      </login-module>
      -->
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
```

The appropriate JAAS config has been set in the following files:

```
$ grep LDAP /usr/share/jbossas/server/node1/deploy/admin-console.war/WEB-INF/*xml
/usr/share/jbossas/server/node1/deploy/admin-console.war/WEB-INF/components.xml:    <security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}" jaas-config-name="LDAP"/>
/usr/share/jbossas/server/node1/deploy/admin-console.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml:    <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">java:/jaas/LDAP</security-domain>
```

Connection with the LDAP server works correctly. I have verified that capturing traffic using `wireshark` and setting `org.jboss.secutiry` logging to `TRACE` in `jboss-log4j.xml`:

```
<category name="org.jboss.security.auth.spi">
  <priority value="TRACE" class="org.jboss.logging.XLevel"></priority>
</category>
```

I have also set `DEBUG` level for the `org.jboss.seam` component:

```
<category name="org.jboss.seam">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
```

which also verifies that the authentication step is working correctly:

```
2014-06-09 16:42:41,189 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.security.Identity] (http-192.0.2.1-8080-6) Login successful for: someuser
```

There seems to be a problem with authorization, I can't access the `admin-console` even though the user is correctly authenticated. I've tried two different approaches:

1. As I don't have a group in my LDAP named `JBossAdmin` (which is the role used by default):

   ```
   $ grep JBossAdmin -R *
   facelets/resourceNavigation.xhtml:        <h:form id="navTreeForm" rendered="#{s:hasRole('JBossAdmin')}">
   pages.xml:            <rule if="#{s:hasRole('JBossAdmin')}">
   pages.xml:        <restrict>#{s:hasRole('JBossAdmin')}</restrict>
   web.xml:        <role-name>JBossAdmin</role-name>
   ```

   I'm trying to map my LDAP groups and JBoss roles using the `RoleMappingLoginModule`:

   ```
     <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule" flag="optional">
       <module-option name="rolesProperties">props/admin-console-roles.properties</module-option>
     </login-module>
   ```

   The contents of the `props/admin-console-roles.properties` is:

   ```
   someuser=JBossAdmin
   ```

   as documented, the syntax is `username=role1,role2`.
2. Replace the occurrences of `JBossAdmin` with one of the groups present in the LDAP structure, say `developers`:

   ```
   $ grep developers -R *
   facelets/resourceNavigation.xhtml:        <h:form id="navTreeForm" rendered="#{s:hasRole('developers')}">
   pages.xml:            <rule if="#{s:hasRole('developers')}">
   pages.xml:        <restrict>#{s:hasRole('developers')}</restrict>
   web.xml:        <role-name>developers</role-name>
   ```

Neither of the two work. I'm stuck at the login page.Moreover, if I insist and press the login button again, I'm greeted with this:

[image: admin-console]

How can I debug it further? Is it possible to map LDAP groups to roles in JBoss 5? Can group names (instead of user names) be used in a `role.properties` file when using `RoleMappingLoginModule`?